# Add existing project to solution "read only" in Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to add an existing project to a solution in "read-only" mode?

I got access to a big bunch of internal projects, from which I just need some functions for another solution. Since I'm new to the original solution I'd like to make sure I don't accidentally change any of the existing files and check them into the TFS.

The easiest way to do so, would be some sort of "Add existing project (read only)"-Function.
Is there any way to do so? Or are there any other ways to ensure I'm not accidentally changing any of the existing files?

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the source controled version to a seperate folder, and then reference that one from you Solution. your not working with source controlled code then , so you can't break it!

Comment: I already though of that - but on the other hand I'd like to make sure I always got the latest version. And as little repetative work as possible ;-)

Comment: set a second workspace, keep the solution in one workspace and the project in another, when you check in for the solution then your project would be unaffected as it exists in a different workspace